# Swift - Return value from locationManager function in class extension

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get directions from the users current location to a destination using Google Maps. I want this to be done when the showDirection button is pressed, however I can't figure how to return or pass the users location into the IBAction function from func locationManager(... didUpdateLocation) as the IBAction doesn't use parameters in which I can pass locValue to.

Here is the showDirection button function:

```
@IBAction func showDirection(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Running showDirection")
    let instanceOne = ParseViewController() // Create ParseViewController instance to operate on
    print("Created ParseView instance")
    let Coord = instanceOne.returnParse()
    let latitude = (Coord.lat as NSString)
    let longitude = (Coord.long as NSString)
    var urlString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?"
    urlString += "saddr= // Users location from didUpdateLocation"
    urlString += "&daddr= \(latitude as String), \(longitude as String)"
    print(urlString)

    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

and here is the locationManager function with the locValue:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = (manager.location?.coordinate)!
        print("Coordinates = \(locValue.latitude), \(locValue.longitude)")
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an internal variable in the class to store the location if you want to use it in another function. E.g.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController ... {
    var lastLocation: CLLocation? = nil
    ...
}
```

In `didUpdateLocations`:

```
if let location = locations.first {
    lastLocation = location
    ...
}
```

And now you can access it in `func showDirection()`